# Comment Authors of Post On Front Page

Tags: posts

You can get the post author on the front page, but I'd like to be able to list all comment authors of a specific post on the front page. Tried a few ways to no avail and Google doesn't reveal much.

See GrowthHackers.com for example.

Answer (score 0):

Google will reveal all, if you know what your looking for.

You can get all comment authors by using the [get_comments()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments#Examples) function.

In fact the first example listed there will exactly what you want.

```
<?php 
$comments = get_comments('post_id=15');
foreach($comments as $comment) :
    echo($comment->comment_author);
endforeach;
?>
```